# Angular Bootstrap Datepicker directive to minimize html elements

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angularjs-directive

We are using Angular UI bootstrap implementation for date picker in our project. I need to write many HTML element for date picker, would it be a good idea to write a directive for such tasks? If yes please help me to provide sample code for any such directive.

```
<p class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup ng-model="leaveSearch.td" is-open="$parent.dtLeaveToOpen" ng-required="true" />
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="datePickerOpen($event,'dtLeaveTo','dtLeaveToOpen')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
              </span>
            </p>
```

How can wrap all this into single html element, I think using Angular directive we can achieve this. I am looking for similar idea.

Comment: Angular UI has a datepicker directive. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date `<input ui-date>`

Comment: ui-date is jQuery based implementation. we want some bootstrap ui based implementation.

Comment: There is also the Angular UI Bootstrap Datepicker, which depends only on Bootstrap (no jQuery): http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Hey Thilo, I am using Angular UI bootstrap only. I want to have some directive to reduce this code. Edited my question for the same.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I wrote below directive which worked for me:

```
 angularStartDirectives.directive('espireDate', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            show: '=',            
            ngModel: '=',
            ngClass: '=',
            ngRequired:'='
        },
        replace: true, // Replace with the template below
        transclude: true, // we want to insert custom content inside the directive
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.open = false;
            scope.dpOpen = function () { 
                scope.open = true;                
            };
        },
        template: '<div><div class="input-group  input-group-lg" ng-click="dpOpen()" >'
           + ' <input id="attrs.id" readonly="true" type="text" class="form-control" data-is-open="open" datepicker-popup data-ng-model="ngModel" ng-class="ngClass" ng-required="ngRequired" />'
            + ' <span class="input-group-addon">'
                + '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>'
            + '</span></div></div>'   
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I don't know why this type of implementation is not more popular. It seems to make a lot of sense. Maybe my google-fu is just off today.